# Use Scroll Lock key for terminal flow control

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, scrolling

So, my <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> key doesn't have much use, while I keep hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> with no intention of stopping control flow.

I know how to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> from locking scroll (`stty -ixon`), but can I use <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> key instead for the same use?

**- UPDATE -**

In my terminal <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> does not stop control flow. My question is how to assign that function to that key.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stty stop undef` and `stty start undef`.  This way, C-s and C-q are being freed for other purposes, but ScrLock still controls flow.

This might be shell and/or terminal-specific, though.

Comment: In my terminal Scrool Lock does not stop control flow. I was looking exactly looking for a way to assign that function to that key. I will update the question to be more clear.

Comment: which terminal is it, then?

Comment: I'm not sure. Is Konsole (from KDE) a terminal?

Comment: Yes, it is.   Which version of KDE?

Comment: KDE v.4.14.2; Konsole Version 2.14.2